# Least squares with non-linear constraints

Tags: optimization, least-squares, nonlinear

I have the following problem:

I want to minimize a least square problem with non-linear restrictions. The start model has the following form:

$$w^*=\text{min arg}_w \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i-\sum_{j=1}^3 w_jx_{ij})^2$$
where $w \in R.$

I minimized error at above model using least-square method.
My model is now more complicated. I will describe the new complication. Let $T>0$ be a threshold which is given as input.
All the absolute differences which are not in the interval $[-T,T]$ introduce the error $T^2$.

The model becomes:

$$w^*=\text{arg min}_w\sum_{i=1}^N  S_i(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^3 w_jx_{ij})^2+\sum_{i=1}^N T^2 (1-S_i)$$

where $\forall i \in 1,\dots, N$ we have the following constraints:

$$S_i(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^3 w_jx_{ij})^2<=T^2,$$
where $
S_{i} \in \{0,1\}
$.

$S_i$ is not known at input and must be determined.
How can I solve this optimization problem?

Comment: If we define $\psi(x)=x^2$ for $x\in[-T,T]$, $\psi(x)=T$ for $|x|\ge T$ then your problem is to find  $\text{argmin}_w\sum_{i=1}^n\psi(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^3w_jx_{ij})$. This looks similar to winsorised mean problem. I think the theory of minimizing $\sum\psi(\varepsilon_i)$ is quite developed, so you can find something if you search specifically for that.

Answer (score 5):

As I've said in the comment, this is not a constrained optimisation problem, i.e. there are no constraints.

Define

$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}T^2,|x|>T\\x^2,|x|\le T\end{cases}$$

Then the optimisation problem can be rewritten as

$$w^*=\text{argmin}_w\sum_{i=1}^n\psi\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^nx_{ij}w_j\right)$$

Such types of minimisation problems were first considered by P. J. Huber in 1964. This particular problem then is a [robust statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) problem. More complicated example is [least trimmed squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_trimmed_squares), where the portion of largest in absolute value errors are discarded. The latter method is implemented in R package **robustbase** with function `lmrob`.

For your particular problem you can use `optim`. Here is the example (in R). First setup dummy data and functions:

```
 psi <- function(x,T) { 
   x[abs(x)>T]<-T
   x^2
 }

 optfun <- function(w,T) {
     sum(psi(y-X%*%w,T=T))
 }

 ##Create sample data set    
 set.seed(13)
 X <- cbind(1,rnorm(100))
 y <- 1+ 0.5*X[,2] + rnorm(100)/2

 ##Contaminate data 
 smpl <- sample(1:100,10)
 X[smpl,2] <- 10
```

Now run the optimisation:

```
> optim(c(0,0),optfun,T=2)
$par
[1] 0.95419635 0.03152925

$value
[1] 48.39998

$counts
function gradient 
      77       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

See the slope is far from the true value. Reduce the value of $T$:

```
> optim(c(0,0),optfun,T=1)
$par
[1] 1.0072015 0.5557612

$value
[1] 31.67965

$counts
function gradient 
      63       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Now we get the true values. In this simple example I ignored all the possible optimisation issues, i.e. the choice of starting values and choice of optimisation method. It is not hard to extend this code to produce standard errors of the coefficient estimates, see package **numDeriv**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. But I want further to reduce the error. I want to know if exist a method which for the $x_{i,j}$ and $y_i$ defined above I can obtain a matrix of weights $w$ with size $K \times 3$, $K>1$ and the necessary rules to minimize the error. At input I want to know the good rules to select necessary weights from matrix $w$ to apply to $x_{ij}$ elements in order to minimize square errors.

Comment: Your $w$ is of dimension $1\times 3$. What is $K$ then? How does this comment relates to your question?

Comment: Sorry, not following you. What is the initial problem you are trying to solve? And what is predictor in your problem? $y$? And what is an input variable? Could you please talk in terms of the quantities defined in your question? I am mightily confused.

Comment: Sorry for the my presentation. The predictor in my problem is $w*$. I want to know if $w*$ can be a matrix with the size $K \times 3$ where $K$ is fixed. In the function defined above the value of $K$ was 1.